# How to build object with many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 models User, Course and Group. Their relationship is as follows

user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
  belongs_to :group
```

group.rb

```
has_many :users
  belongs_to :course
```

course.rb

```
has_many :groups,  dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

I want to create a new group. How can I build group object? My user and course objects are below

```
   def new
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @course = Course.find(params[:course])
    @group = need to build object here
  end
```

Previously I used to do something like this

```
@group = @user.groups.build
```

But now I also have @course object. How can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
 def new
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @course = Course.find(params[:course])
    @group = @user.build_group(course: @course)
    # you can do @user.create_group!(course: @course) to create
    # the object in-place instead of in memory.
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   def new
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @course = Course.find(params[:course])
    @group = @course.build_group(:user => @user)
  end
```

try this